# Symfony + API Platform: Is there a way to throw an error when POST data has unexpected (eg. mistyped) properties?

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

Say I have an API resource named "Foo" with property "bar" and I make the POST operation available to create a new instance:

```
POST /api/foo
{
   "bar": "whatever"
}
```

If the user of my API mis-types the property like so:

```
POST /api/foo
{
   "bat": "whatever"
}
```

There is no error.

I could add a NotNull constraint on the property "bar" so that if "bar" was not included, then an error would be thrown, but what to do if "bar" is nullable? Right now the result will be that "bar" becomes NULL and that is not what the end user expected.

Alternately, if any additional properties are added, there is no error or warning thrown, for example if "publish" is not a property but the following is submitted:

```
POST /api/foo
{
   "bar": "whatever",
   "publish": true
}
```

There is no error or warning about the unexpected "publish" property. The end user might expect this property to be available, possibly because it exists on other resources, but there is no error in the response. Obviously the end user should be reading documentation, but I would prefer giving feedback directly in the response to ensure 100% compliance.

In summary:
If users of my API add erroneous properties, or accidentally mistype property names, how can I detect this and throw an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realised this would have something to do with the denormalizing step, and eventually found this:

```
/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     denormalizationContext={"allow_extra_attributes"=false}
 * )
 */
```

Ref: https://github.com/api-platform/core/issues/1217#issuecomment-488662805

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Groups annotation with denormalization_context. So you declare the properties who's granted to be updated. And using strong type-hint

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

/**
 * Class Foo
 * @package AppBundle\Entity
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ApiResource(
 *  attributes={
 *      "normalization_context"={"groups"={"get"}},
 *      "denormalization_context"={"groups"={"put, "post"}}
 *  },
 *  itemOperations={},
 *  collectionOperations={"post"}
 * ) 
 */
class Foo
{
    /**
     * @var string 
     * @ORM\Column(name="bar", type="string", nullable=false) 
     * @Groups({"get", "post"}) 
     */
    private string $bar;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="bar", type="string", nullable=false)
     * @Groups({"get"}) 
     */
    private string $bat;

    /**
     * @var bool 
     * @ORM\Column(name="public", type="boolean", nullable=false)
     * @Groups({"get", "post"})
     */
    private bool $public;

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBar(): string
    {
        return $this->bar;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $bar
     *
     * @return Foo
     */
    public function setBar(string $bar): Foo
    {
        $this->bar = $bar;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBat(): string
    {
        return $this->bat;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $bat
     *
     * @return Foo
     */
    public function setBat(string $bat): Foo
    {
        $this->bat = $bat;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isPublic(): bool
    {
        return $this->public;
    }

    /**
     * @param bool $public
     *
     * @return Foo
     */
    public function setPublic(bool $public): Foo
    {
        $this->public = $public;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

You can see that property $bat don't have group annotation "post": so this field is not authorized in your POST request. You can add too some Constraints: for example :

```php
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint as Assert;

//...
    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="bar", type="string", nullable=false)
     * @Groups({"get", "post"})
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="property bar is mandatory")
     */
    private string $bar;
```

I hope it will be helpfull.

Comment: Hi, I think you misunderstood my question. "bat" and "publish" are *not* properties of the resource, but an example of a typo from the end user. I want to throw an error if *any* extra property is in the input that is *not* a known property of the resource.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstood. Groups annotations are not enough ? If an extra property is added, the denormalization_context (for POST, PUT) will block and no data will be added in BD.
Other way, look about controller Special to check body parameter:
you get your body param with ` $getContentBody = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);` and with ReflexionClass on your entity you can retrieve all your properties.
Then check if body parameters are in list of your properties and if not, throw error. I have an example, if you want, i can make an other answer with this example

Comment: Hi, I am already using group annotations, and no, they do not block extra properties. You can submit a POST with any additional properties that do not belong to the resource, and API will not throw an error. The properties get ignored, but I would like to show an error to the user. I would prefer a solution that involves extending API Platform, rather than relying on accessing request data directly, which seems like a dirty hack.

Comment: I looked to API Platform documentation and it's look like controller special are for old version (i'm working with a 2.2 version :/, so maybe not a solution for you). Have you think to create a custom DataProvider https://api-platform.com/docs/core/data-providers/#custom-collection-data-provider or a custom controller: https://api-platform.com/docs/core/controllers/#creating-custom-operations-and-controllers ?
I don't have other idea, sorry.